# Overlapping Geometry Nodes cause visibility issues

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have two geometry nodes set up on different objects, one inside the other. The layout looks like this:[image]

However, in the material preview, viewport shading, and final render, the inner geometry is somehow "rendered out" by the outer geometry. When I switch to Cycles, the same thing happens for the material preview, but the viewport shading view and render look how I expect them to. Here's the material preview (in Eevee).
[image]

I previously had this set up as a single geometry nodes modifier using the Join Geometry node, which strangely caused the opposite problem (i. e., the inner geometry was completely visible through the outer geometry). For whatever reason both issues go away as long as I don't assign any material to the outer geometry. Currently I just have a default principled BSDF material assigned for testing purposes.

Here are the geometry nodes for inner and outer geometries respectively:
[image]
[image]

And here are the shaders for inner and outer geometries respectively:
[image]
[image]

I'm pretty new to Blender, so hopefully this is just something simple I'm overlooking. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: check out the blending mode of the material. Make sure it's set to opaque

Comment: Ah thanks, that does fix it! 
I was hoping to play around with transparency later, but it seems like Alpha Hash also gets rid of the weird transparency artifacts. Only alpha blend causes issues. For some reason, deleting the other (non-emissive) light source also makes alpha blend behave better, as long as it's only on the exterior material. Lots to learn.